# kivy.clock vs threading of python

Tags: multithreading, kivy, kivymd, producer-consumer

I am currently developing an Android app using Kivy and have a requirement to execute certain functions in a separate thread. I understand that Python threads are typically employed for parallel task execution. Additionally, I've come across Kivy's clock.schedule_once(function, t) method, which I believe can run a function in another thread after a specified time 't'. This leads me to wonder if both Python threads and Kivy Clock can be used interchangeably to run functions in threads other than the main one. If this is the case, could you please clarify the specific scenarios in which each approach is more suitable?

Is it possible to utilize kivy.clock.schedule_once for adding a widget from a Python thread, as an alternative to using @mainthread?

For both cases (Python threads and Kivy Clock), I aim to add or modify a widget, understanding that UI-related operations should be performed in the main thread. Can you provide guidance on how to achieve this in both scenarios, perhaps with an illustrative example?

I have independently researched Python threads and Kivy's clock.schedule_once. I would greatly appreciate your assistance in clarifying the questions I've raised.

Comment: Python Threads run code in a thread that is not the main thread, so you cannot do GUI updates in such a thread. The `Clock.schedule_once()` and `Clock.schedule_interval()` schedule methods to be run on the main thread, so you can modify the GUI in such a method. Note that you do not want to run long running methods on the main thread, because the GUI only updates itself on the main thread. If you have the main thread busy with something else, the GUI will freeze until you free up the main thread.